# CSS Styling Issues When <sup> Has 2 lines

Tags: html, css

So I have a price in a span tag and a "per person" in a sup tag

```
<span class="price">R500</span><sup>per person</sup>
```

It superscript is all in one line but I want 'person' to appear beneath 'per' but not beneath the span tag with the price.

My Q: How to put paragraphs, breaks, space between 2 words in superscript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a `<br/>` tag inside the `<sup>` element. Then assign `display: inline-block;` to the CSS of <sup>. You can then align the text using `vertical-align`.

See this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BE7y8/

Comment: And here I was trying to cook up a jQuery solution... Nicely done!

Comment: Superscript is just being used for my styling purposes. Regardless of its use it fixed my prob.

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use an HTMl like:

```
<sup>per <span>person</span></sup>
```

and style the nested span according to your visual goal?

Comment: I did, but it still jumped to the line under the price

Comment: Yup @ObiWanKobi it is probably better to just add the `<br />` tag as pointed by @KristianFrost